# rust async callback or channel

Tags: asynchronous, rust, callback, channel, rust-tokio

Sorry for a question with no code involved. I'm not sure whether this is the best place to ask but I don't know of a better place.

I have a code library which does cool stuff. It reads from multiple http and websocket sources, accumulates the information and sends real-time reports (through http). It is built on `async`. There are two ways two do the publisher-subcriber pattern between parts of the lib that receive info, analyze and send and I have to choose.

1. pass callbacks to publishers. When they get new information they go through callbacks and call them
2. pass data received by publishers into mpsc channels and subscribers read from those channels

My questions:

1. Are channels substantially higher latency (there must be additional code that routes between channels somewhere under the hood)?
2. Are callbacks or channels easier to read and reason about? E.g. in order to understand where in the code the information flow goes
3. What are substantial restrictions that channels might have vs callbacks (which I suppose are more general)

Thank you!

Comment: It might be important to know that how your publishers provide the data? Are your publishers' count dynamically change?  Also the `mpsc` channel, which one you are planning to use?

Comment: Tokio mpsc channel was in my plan. The number of publishers is static. Some of them I ask through rest every n seconds. With others there is websocket channel open and I listen to new data

Comment: This means you are working with [Streams](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html), `mpsc` might be a good idea since you want to join multiple `Stream` to a single `Stream`. Passing closure might not work efficient here since your accumulator/reporter logic needs to be managed across multiple threads. To make my report logic clear; I'd  implement custom `Future`  and poll my bundled resources with [SelectAll](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/fn.select_all.html), or poll individually regarding their importance(since counted static) then do the reporting.

Comment: May I ask why you say closure? I was thinking more of methods on some structs. Or that would be a closure?

Comment: Since you are suggesting channels/streams do you have anything to say regarding the questions I have in my question?

Comment: _I was thinking more of methods on some structs._  This is how closure works under the hood and I believe I answered some of your questions regarding your problem's context.